# Getting error unknown type name 'size_t' even though I've included the relevant C libraries and headers

Tags: c, netfilter

Please find my code below.
I am getting the error "/usr/include/linux/sysctl.h:40:2: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’"

Searching online, the only suggestion is to make sure you have stddef.h included in your code, which I do as can be seem below. There does not appear to be a solution available outside of this fix, which I have tried, so I am currently at a loss as to how to move forward.

Also note, this code is not pretty, but that is not the main issue with this thread. The error I am getting does not look like it is being thrown from a mistake in my code, but I may be wrong.

```
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct nf_hook_ops{

        struct list_head *list;

        nf_hookfn *hook;

        struct module *owner;

        u_int8_t pf;

        unsigned int hooknum;

        int priority;    /* Hooks are ordered in ascending priority. */

};

int nf_register_hook(struct nf_hook_ops *reg);

void nf_unregister_hook(struct nf_hook_ops *reg);


struct nf_hook_ops nfho = {

    nfho.hook = hook_func_in,     

    nfho.hooknum = NF_INET_LOCAL_IN,     

    nfho.pf = PF_INE, 

    nfho.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST
};

nf_register_hook(&nfho);         // Register the hook
```

Comment: I can't see any `size_t` in your code. Try to include `<stddef.h>` before the other header files.

Comment: If you had included one of your own headers, then I would advise you to look for a mis-math (brace, quote, processor directive, etc). As it is, I can't help :-(

Comment: @machine_1 I saw that too. I think that teh OP should post the complete error message, the one that shows `included from ... included from .. included from ...`, as that might make it obvious

Comment: The relative order of *system* headers should not matter, but perhaps the kernel sources are not wholly up to speed with that.

Comment: size_t is not mentioned anywhere in my code, I know. This looks like it's a compilation error with libraries referenced from other libraries I'm using. Please find the full error messages in this imgur link https://imgur.com/a/nY7J3

Comment: I would expect from kernel headers to not have such a stupid mistakes...

Comment: okay, wow, moving the #include <stddef.h> to the top of the code has resolved this error it looks like. Thank you all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C is parsed strictly top to bottom, and `#include` does plain old textual inclusion, not anything clever that would qualify for the name of "module import".  Therefore, the order of `#include` directives can matter.  In this case, you're getting complaints about a type defined by `stddef.h`, so you must make sure that `stddef.h` is included *before* whatever needs it, which could be (indeed, is) another header file.

I can reproduce the error you're getting with the following two-line source file:

```
#include <linux/sysctl.h>
#include <stddef.h>
```

→

```
$ gcc -fsyntax-only test.c
In file included from test.c:1:0:
/usr/include/linux/sysctl.h:39:2: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
```

If I exchange the order of the `#include` lines,

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <linux/sysctl.h>
```

then there is no error.  This is a bug in `linux/sysctl.h`, but I would not hold my breath for it to be fixed.  I recommend moving `stddef.h` to the very top of the include list.

I can *not* reproduce the problem with your actual list of includes,

```
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <stddef.h>
```

but a `gcc -H` dump does not show `linux/sysctl.h` getting pulled in transitively by that set of includes, so probably it's just that I have a different version of the kernel headers on my Linux box than you do.

Comment: This works, thank you so much! It was such a weird error, I would not have thought of this on my own.

Comment: The more general lesson you should learn here is that in C the order of `#include`s can matter.